# Warning BK4504: файл содержит слишком много ссылок

Tags: c++, visual-studio, компиляция

Как вычислить, где проблема?

> `Link:
> 1>c:\включени _c++ 2012\xtree(386): warning BK4504: файл содержит слишком много ссылок; дальнейшие ссылки из этого источника будут игнорироваться`

Проблема в том, что перевел проект в многомодульный режим. Средний .cpp файл стал компилироваться 1-3 секунды.

Затем что-то случилось, но не помню, что и где именно менял. Возникла эта ошибка и время компиляции выросло до 8-15 секунд для всех файлов cpp. Компилирование (`ClCompile:`) выполняется по прежнему быстро. А вот линковка - очень долго. Warning (`Link:`) вылетает как раз после линковки.

Как вычислить этот cpp файл, в котором так много ссылок?

Comment: Хм. Может для начала убрать кириллицу в пути? Да и вообще - собирайте релизную версию проекта, а не отладочную.

Comment: В release всё нормально. Быстро и без warning.

Ну а сама суть проблемы?
То что файл содержит много ссылок, это 

    #inсlude
    
    или
    
    например 
    std::map<vector<map<..>>>


Я просто не могу понять, нигде не описано что приводит к такому предупреждению.

Comment: Конкретно опцию что приводит к ошибке нашел:

свойства конфигурации/C++/информация об исходном коде/ включить информацию об исходном коде - ДА(/FR)


> При её включении срабатывает такая
> ошибка в release. BSCMAKE : error
> BK1500: Internal error


Про неё подробнее написано, что BSCMAKE больше не поддерживается с vs 2010.
Раньше использовался для работы с MFC и подобными крупными библиотеками.


То есть вероятно ошибок в самом коде скорее всего нету(связанных с этим warning)?

Comment: Ну, bscmake по моим представлениям делает отладочную информацию, а конкретнее - создает таблицу символов в специальном формате, чтобы потрм можно было ею пользоваться в отладчике. Про то, что с 2010 bscmake не работает слышу впервые.